# Learning Ruby, but First Finding out what it is?

Tags: ruby

I have just bought a Ruby on Rails book, but I am going to learn Ruby as much as possible through the internet first.

The first thing I need to know is, what is Ruby and what do I need to run it?

Is it likely to be installed on my Linux/Apache server or will I need to have them install it? Is it even a web based language or is it like Java or C, any help, advice, tips all gratefully received, especially if you can point me to a good tutorial to start me off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take jaunt over to the Ruby website - http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/ and begin there.  Personally, I found this site to be a good introduction to Ruby - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Essentials.  There is a site where you can run the code without even installing it - http://tryruby.org/.  I think this should allow you to get to know the language well enough to decide if you want to go any further.

Answer (score 3):

> what is Ruby

A programming language.

> and what do I need to run it?

A computer that has Ruby installed.

Comment: This ought to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Andrew: I disagree. I answered the two specific questions the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with [Ruby-lang.org](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) (including the tutorial in the link).

Beyond that, IMO another excellent activity to learn Ruby is the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), which help you learn idiomatic ruby through fixing failed unit tests.

Book-wise, for Rails I had good luck with [Head First Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515774).  I'm currently chewing through [The Ruby Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328844), which has been great for learning more idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

If your interest is in learning Ruby on Rails, and are a total beginner, you would do well to start with Michael Hartl's http://railstutorial.org/

It is the best one-stop resource for a newbie; and it is a much efficient way to learn rails than to go about learning stuff on the internet.

In addition to teaching Rails framework, the book teaches the reader about the tools essential to existence in the Rails Community, such as Git, GitHub, Heroku, RubyGems, Test Driven Development with RSpec. There is adequate treatment of relevant topics required for becoming a Rails developer - HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and the relevant parts of Ruby language. And there are suggestions for further reading to advance the skills in each of these.

The book begins with a chapter with easy to follow steps for installing all relevant components on various OSes, including Linux.

Answer (score 1):

When I learned Ruby and Rails I started with Pragmatic Programmers' Agile Web Development with Ruby on Rails (1st edition) and worked my way back into Ruby from there. If I had it to do over I would have picked up Programming Ruby (also from Pragmatic Programmers) at the same time--as it was I picked up bits and pieces of Ruby as I went, and didn't really sit down and learn Ruby for about a year, even though I was creating Rails apps for production.

These days I think Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial site, already mentioned, is the best way to go.

In addition, [Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book](http://humblelittlerubybook.com/) is an overlooked but good introduction to the Ruby language. It's available as a free PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Ruby the Hardway is a good book to start with

http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/